# Why is this binary file seemingly non-executable?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, binary-files

I would like to execute this binary file: `/usr/bin/snx` (CheckPoint Security VPN client)

When I execute `snx` or `sudo snx` from anywnere, the responses are:

```
bash: /usr/bin/snx: No such file or directory
```

or

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/snx: No such file or directory
```

The file is present int the location and has the sufficient rights:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root       4156692 jún   29 09:56  snx
```

When I navigate to `/usr/bin/` and execute either `./snx` or `sudo ./snx`, the answer is the same as above.

The file has valid content, starts with the magic string `ELF`.

What am I doing wrong? I know it is simple, but still.

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/133389/693277) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3949161).

Comment: You need 32-bits libs...see my post for how to install, what to install and how to use it.https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450229/getting-checkpoint-vpn-ssl-network-extender-working-in-command-line/450230

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error due to architecture incompatibility.

```
$ld snx
ld: i386 architecture of input file `snx' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
ld: error in snx(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 000000000049e040
```

Comment: Good answer. But if the architecture is incompatible, how can it even be installed to begin with.